# Deploying a BPM project into remote BPM Suite with BuildProject asset management process

Tags: jboss, jbpm, guvnor

I'm trying to deploy a BPM project with business-central provided tools (the BuildProject asset management process) into a remote BPM Suite but I'm getting an error. Is it possible to deploy an asset of one BPM Suite instance into a different one installed in a different server? I'm using jBoss BPM Suite 6.2.

**1. Trying to deploy the project in BPM Suite #1 into BPM Suite #2**

Here is a link with a screenshot of the deployment parameters [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv2em.png)

**2. Trace in BPM Suite #1 (origin)**

```
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (http-/xx.xx.xxx.183:8080-1) Auto approve for user: JbpmAdmin
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (http-/xx.xx.xxx.183:8080-1) Operation : Build and deploy project
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (http-/xx.xx.xxx.183:8080-1) Repository : pruebasrepositorios/flujosaprobacion
INFO  [AssetMgmt] (http-/xx.xx.xxx.183:8080-1) Project : null
INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xx.xxx.183:8080-1) Start assets management process: BuildProject  Tue Apr 19 17:41:09 CEST 2016
INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (Thread-273 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-121738450)) KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (Thread-269 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-121738450)) KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
INFO  [org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils] (Thread-269 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-121738450)) Not in OSGi: using plexus based maven parser
INFO  [stdout] (Thread-269 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-121738450)) End assets management process: BuildProject  Tue Apr 19 17:41:11 CEST 2016
```

**3. Trace in BPM Suite #2 (remote)**

```
WARN  [org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository] (Thread-1246 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1686476357)) Unable to resolve artifact: arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
WARN  [org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository] (Thread-1246 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1686476357)) Unable to resolve artifact: arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
WARN  [org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository] (Thread-1246 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1686476357)) Unable to resolve artifact: arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
WARN  [org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService] (Thread-1246 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1686476357)) Unexpected error while deploying unit arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:117) [drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:111) [drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:132) [jbpm-kie-services-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [jbpm-services-cdi-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.kie.remote.services.rest.async.cmd.DeploymentCmd.execute(DeploymentCmd.java:67) [kie-remote-services-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.executor.impl.AbstractAvailableJobsExecutor.executeGivenJob(AbstractAvailableJobsExecutor.java:122) [jbpm-executor-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.executor.impl.jms.JmsAvailableJobsExecutor.onMessage(JmsAvailableJobsExecutor.java:47) [jbpm-executor-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:86) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:97) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:93) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:203) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at javax.jms.MessageListener$$$view11.onMessage(Unknown Source) [jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-3]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:140) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy216.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:330)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1117)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:57)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1252)
        at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:105)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]

ERROR [org.kie.remote.services.rest.async.cmd.DeploymentCmd] (Thread-1246 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1686476357)) Unable to deploy [arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:193) [jbpm-kie-services-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(DeploymentServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [jbpm-services-cdi-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.kie.remote.services.rest.async.cmd.DeploymentCmd.execute(DeploymentCmd.java:67) [kie-remote-services-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.executor.impl.AbstractAvailableJobsExecutor.executeGivenJob(AbstractAvailableJobsExecutor.java:122) [jbpm-executor-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.executor.impl.jms.JmsAvailableJobsExecutor.onMessage(JmsAvailableJobsExecutor.java:47) [jbpm-executor-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:86) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:97) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:93) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:203) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at javax.jms.MessageListener$$$view11.onMessage(Unknown Source) [jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-3]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:140) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy216.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:330)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1117)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:57)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1252)
        at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:105)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: arquitectura.pruebasrepositorios:flujosaprobacion:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:117) [drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:111) [drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.KModuleDeploymentService.deploy(KModuleDeploymentService.java:132) [jbpm-kie-services-6.3.0.Final-redhat-9.jar:6.3.0.Final-redhat-9]
        ... 73 more
```